# Getting a Undefined Method Error for an Array Call in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following method in my program:

```
def crawl_urls(urlArray)
    urlArray.count.times do |i| 
        puts "now crawling site " + i.to_s + "<--------"
        has_email?(urlArray[i])
    end
end
```

The error message is :

```
*******.rb:126:in `block in scrape_urls': undefined method `[]' for 1..2:Range (NoMethodError)
```

The offending line, according to the error message being:

```
has_email?(urlArray[i])
```

Comment: What's `urlArray`? It appears it's not what you think it is. Also, what's the point of doing `count.times` when you could use `each_with_index`?

Comment: Yeah, `urlArray` is not, in fact, an array

Comment: According to the error message, you call `crawl_urls(1..2)`

Comment: @Stefan, yes, it was a bad call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way of expressing this is:

```
def crawl_urls(urls)
  urls.each_with_index do |url, i|
    puts "now crawling site #{i} <--------"
    has_email?(url)
  end
end
```

There's no need to do `times` to get an offset, and then go back and look up things in the array when `each` will do that for you.

Another thing to note is to avoid putting upper-case letters in Ruby variables or method names. `urlArray` should be `url_array` or even better, as it's a more natural way of expressing it, `urls`.

Answer (score 0):

A range is not an array. Use `.to_a` on your range to convert it and be able to use `[]`